# Why is modalpopupextender response time depending on parent page content?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, ajaxcontroltoolkit

`Show()` and especially `Close()` take way more time than they should. Even when I blank out everything on the popup content other than a close button. No database connections etc( absolutely no content). My page has eight update panels each with data lists in them. Five of the panels have refresh timers (1 minute interval). My modalpopupextender (which is in a user control) is in one of the panels.

When I remove all the other update panels (there is nothing else on the page), `Show()` and `Close()` respond fast. I tried jQuery `$find(...).hide()` and still same behavior.

So my question is, why does the content elsewhere on the page have an affect on the popup extender's behavior? Especially even when I am using jQuery's `hide()`? Could it be simply because I just happen to have too many elements on the page that even `getElementById()` is taking so much time to find my extender node?

Comment: `Show` and `Close` execute a postback, so it should take the same time as a regular postback(f.e. due to button-click). All controls must be recreated and the entire lifecycle of the page will be  passed through. Maybe you have things in `Page_Load` which don't belong  there on postbacks.

Comment: @TimSchmelter All my time consuming things in Page_Load are wrapped in !IsPostBack. Also doesn't explain why hide() is slow too.

Answer (score 1):

I also have this problem. For me it turned out to be the size of the viewstate. This is uploaded on every postback and can get very large.